# VBA, 2nd last "/" using InstrRev

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that parses out the last word on a string.
ie. Stack/Over/Flow will give me "Flow".

But I want to get "Over/Flow".

This is what I got, but only able to get "Flow"

`arr(counter - 2) = "'" & mid(Text, InStrRev(Text, "/") + 1) & "'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially misread the question. You can nest `InStrRev()` calls

```
arr(counter - 2) = "'" & mid(Text, InStrRev(Text, "/",InStrRev(Text, "/")-1)+1) & "'"
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use `Split()`

```
Sub lastTwo()
Dim str As String
str = "Stack/Over/Flow"

Dim splt() As String
splt = Split(str, "/")

If UBound(splt) > 0 Then
    Debug.Print splt(UBound(splt) - 1) & "/" & splt(UBound(splt))
End If
End Sub
```

---

Here is a function that does it:

```
Function lastParts(str As String, delim As String, x As Long) As String
Dim splt() As String
splt = Split(str, "/")

If UBound(splt) + 1 >= x Then
   Dim t As String
   t = "=INDEX(INDEX({""" & Join(splt, """;""") & """},N(IF({1},ROW(" & UBound(splt) - x + 2 & ":" & UBound(splt) + 1 & "))),),)"
   lastParts = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate(t)), delim)
Else
    lastParts = str
End If
End Function
```

It has three parts, the string, the delimiter and the number of returns.

It can be called using your code:

```
arr(counter-2) = lastParts(Text,"/",2)
```

or from the worksheet

```
=lastParts(A1,"/",2)
```

[image]

Comment: I personally wouldn't use split as it would only work on values containing 2 slashes  (unless you also include a loop, which is unnecessary imo)... It depends what you want it for ofc.

Comment: I don't understand.  Your own answer only works with two,  the op says two, where am I seeing that there are more or less.

Comment: lmao, I totally misread your answer. xD Not doing well today it seems... xD

Comment: thanks Scott, please dont be offended that I used Sancam answer.

Comment: @excelguy no offense you choose what works best for you.

Comment: @Sancarn I turned it into a loopless function that allows the user to not only dictate the number of returns but the deliminator.

Comment: @excelguy just for fun I turned it into a function and showed how to use it with your code.

Comment: @ScottCraner Lol christ, I have to say that is a pretty innovative use of Excel formula there :P I expect it'd be much faster if it was built with a loop though :P Still really interesting formula :) You could also use recursion, which would theoretically be 'loopless' :P

Comment: Very nice there